# Find coefficient in cubic polynomial

Tags: polynomials, cubics, multinomial-coefficients

We have 
$$ p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx +d$$
where $a, b, c, d$ are complex coefficients. We have to find all posible coefficients for:
$$ p(1) = 2$$
$$ p(i) = i$$
$$ p(-1) = 0$$
Unfortunately I dont know how to start... Have I just put values of $ p(x)$ to the polynomial and calculate it?
I need solution with parameter and after that I have to find polynomial for $$p(1+i) = 0 $$

Comment: Basically, yes. That's a very straight-forward way of doing it. There are others, and while they may potentially save a little bit time and effort on calculation they are more roundabout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach that requires only calculation and no solving, using the Lagrange interpolation formula.

Consider the three functions
$$
p_1(x) = \frac{2}{(1-i)(1-(-1))}(x-i)(x-(-1)) = \frac{1+i}2(x-i)(x+1)\\
p_2(x) = \frac{i}{(i-1)(i-(-1))}(x-1)(x-(-1)) = \frac i2(x-1)(x+1)\\
p_3(x) = \frac{0}{(-1-1)(-1-i)}(x-1)(x-i) = 0
$$
Note that $p_1(1) = 2$, $p_2(i) = i$ and $p_3(-1) = 0$, while
$$
p_1(i) = p_1(-1) = 0\\
p_2(1) = p_2(-1) = 0\\
p_3(1) = p_3(i) = 0
$$
This means that
$$
q(x) = p(x) - (p_1(x) + p_2(x) + p_3(x))
$$
has the property that $q(1) = q(i) = q(-1) = 0$. And since the degree of $q$ is (at most)  $3$, that means that $q$ must be of the form $a(x-1)(x-i)(x-(-1))$ for some constant $a$. And any such $a$ gives a valid $q$. In other words,
$$
p(x) = q(x) + p_1(x) + p_2(x) + p_3(x)
$$
gives all possible solutions to what $p$ could possibly be.

Comment: Ty for answer. Maybe I didnt make a clear question. I edited it. I need solution with parameter and after that I have to find polynomial for $p(1+i) = 0 $

Comment: @no_named_nobody My solution has a parameter, hidden away in the definition of $q$. And if you know the value at a fourth point, then you could use my solution with that parameter as an unknown. Or you could construct the whole thing anew using the same approach, only now with $p_1,p_2,p_3$ and $p_4$, all of them with _three_ factors in the denominator and three linear factors, and also this time there is no need for $q$ as the $p_i$ already have degree $3$.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(1) =2 \implies a+b+c+d=2 \quad \quad \text {(1.)}$$
$$P(-1) =0 \implies -a+b-c+d=0 \quad \quad \text {(2.)}$$

Subtracting $(2.)$ from $(1.)$ ,

$$2a + 2c =2 \implies a+c=1 \quad \quad \text {(3.)}$$

$$P(i) =i \implies -ia - b + ic+ d=i \quad \quad \text {(4.)}$$

Assuming $a = p \,+\,qi$ , we get $c= r \,- \,  qi$ from$ \text {( 4. )}$

Now $$-ia -b+ic+d = i $$

$$ -ip +q -b + ri+q +d =i \implies q=0$$

Hence $a$ and $c$ are real numbers.

Now equating real and imaginary part of $(4.)$ , we get $a=0 ,b=\frac12 ,c=1$ and $d = \frac12$.

So $P(x) = \frac12 x^2 + x + \frac 12.$

Comment: $a,b,c,d$ are complex so you cannot “equate” real and imaginary part

Comment: Ty for answer. Maybe I didnt make a clear question. I edited it. I need solution with parameter and after that I have to find polynomial for $p(1+i) = 0 $

Answer (score 0):

$$P(x)=a(x^2-1)(x-i)+px^2+qx+r$$
$$P(1)=p+q+r=2$$
$$P(i)=-p+iq+r=i$$
$$P(-1)=p-q+r=0$$
Solving we get $q=1$ , $p= r=1/2$
$$P(x)=a(x^2-1)(x-i)+(1/2)x^2+x+(1/2)$$

Comment: Ty for answer. Maybe I didnt make a clear question. I edited it. I need solution with parameter and after that I have to find polynomial for $p(1+i) = 0 $

Comment: As per remember theorem if b=p(a) then b is the remainder when p(X) is divided by (x-a). If that is what your question is then simply put X = 1+I in p(X) you will get p(1+I). If your question is something else then still it is not clear to me what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you set $q(x)=p(x)-(x+1)$ you have that $q(x)$ is a cubic polynomial fulfilling $q(-1)=q(1)=0$ and $q(i)=-1$. The new constraints give $q(x)=(x^2-1)r(x)$ with $r(x)$ being a linear polynomial such that $r(i)=\frac{1}{2}$, i.e. 
$$ r(x) = k(x-i)+\frac{1}{2}.$$
Working backwards it is simple to find the structure of the coefficients of $q(x)$, then the structure of the coefficients of $p(x)$.

Comment: Ty for answer. Maybe I didnt make a clear question. I edited it. I need solution with parameter and after that I have to find polynomial for $p(1+i) = 0 $